# How to make a game character move

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, key-bindings

I need to be able to move the image of the chicken using either a KeyListener and KeyBinding. I can't figure out how to actually make the character move (the chicken), and I need to be able to move him around the frame. It could be done by either using the image as in my code or making it into a swing component.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class primary extends JFrame {
    public primary(){

        //Creates Title Image 
        JLabel title = new JLabel(" ");
        ImageIcon tl = new ImageIcon("title.gif");
        title.setIcon(tl);

        //Creates Start Image
        final JButton start = new JButton("");
        ImageIcon st = new ImageIcon("start.gif");
        start.setIcon(st);

        //Creates Options Image
        JButton options = new JButton("");
        ImageIcon opt = new ImageIcon("options.gif");
        options.setIcon(opt);
        options.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //Create first frame for "Start" button
        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        p1.add(start, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Create second panel for title label
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        p2.add(title, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //Create third panel for "Options" button
        final JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        p3.add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Creates fourth panel to organize all other primary
        final JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        p4.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p4.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);


        //When button is clicked, it changes the level
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(start.isEnabled()) {
                    remove(p4);
                    setSize(1440, 500);
                    add(new ContentPanel1());
                    validate();
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        //Adds fourth panel to frame
        add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        primary frame = new primary();

        //Finds screen size of monitor
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        //Creates the frame
        frame.setTitle("Cockadoodle Duty: Awakening");
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocale(null); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String background = "#000000";
        frame.setBackground(Color.decode(background));
    }
}

class coordinate {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
}

class ContentPanel1 extends JPanel{
    Image back = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("back.gif");
    Image chick = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("chicken.gif");
    Image corn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("corn.gif");

    ContentPanel1() {
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);

        mt.addImage(back, 0);
        try {
            mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        coordinate.x = 20;
        coordinate.y = 321;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int imwidth = back.getWidth(null);
        int imheight = back.getHeight(null);
        g.drawImage(back, 1, 1, null);
        g.drawImage(chick, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, null);
        g.drawImage(corn, 700, 337, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You're hard-coding the coordinate.x and coordinate.y values within the paintComponent method, and doing so will make it impossible to move the chicken.
2. Myself, I wouldn't create a Coordinate class with static values as it's of little use. Instead, why not give the ContentPanel1 class a `private Point chickenLocation` field.
3. I don't see your code attempt to use key bindings anywhere, and without this attempt, it is difficult if not impossible for us to know what you could be doing wrong. If you haven't yet done so, read the [Key Binding tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and first try to give it a go. Sure we could give you the code, but this would cheat you out of the extremely valuable experience of creating it yourself.
4. I'll give you some hints though --

   - I would bind the keys to the JPanel that's doing the drawing.
   - This component has three InputMaps, and I'd use the one associated with the `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` condition. This way the JPanel is not required to have focus for the bindings to work.
   - You will find many examples of using Key Bindings for simple animation on this site, many of them mine. For instance, please check out [this Stackoverflow search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20%5bswing%5d%20%22key%20bindings%22%20).

If you still need help, please show us your code attempt as well as your specific questions about just what confuses you.